# Multiple character replacement in a column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

I am trying to replace some string characters with a single character, I can do it with a multiple lines of code but I was wondering if there is something like this to do it in a single line?

```
df['Column'].str.replace(['_','-','/'], ' ')
```

I can write 3 lines of code for normal str.replace() and change those strings one by one but I don't think that would be efficient.

Answer (score 2):

[**Pandas Dataframe Str**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) replace takes regex pattern or string as first argument. So you can provide a regex to change multiple patterns

**code:**

```
import pandas as pd
check_df = pd.DataFrame({"Column":["abc", "A_bC", "A_b-C/d"]})
check_df['Column'].str.replace("_|-|/", " ")
```

**Output:**

```
0        abc
1       A bC
2    A b C d
Name: Column, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a regular expression with an alternating group:

```py
df['Column'].str.replace(r"_|-|/", " ", regex=True)
```

`|` means "either of these".

or you can use `str.maketrans` to make a translation table and use `.str.translate`:

```py
df['Column'].str.translate(str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys("_-|", " ")))
```

Note that this is for 1-length characters' translation.

---

If characters are dynamically produced, e.g., within a list, then `re.escape("|".join(chars))` can be used for the first way, and `"".join(chars)` for the second way. `re.escape` for the first one is for special characters' escaping, e.g., if "$" is to be replaced, since it is the end-of-string anchor in regexes, we need to have written "\$" instead, which `re.escape` will take care.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a character class `[/_-]` listing the characters that you want to replace.

Note that if you have multiple consecutive characters and you replace them with a space, you will get space gaps. If you don't want that, you can repeat the character class with a `+` to match 1 or more characters and replace that match with a single space.

If you don't want the leading and trailing spaces, you can use `.str.strip()`

Example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Column":["       a//b_c__-d", "a//////b      "]})
df['Column'] = df['Column'].str.replace(r"[/_-]", ' ')
print(df)

print("\n---------v2---------\n")

df_v2 = pd.DataFrame({"Column":["       a//b_c__-d", "a//////b      "]})
df_v2['Column'] = df_v2['Column'].str.replace(r"[/_-]+", ' ').str.strip()
print(df_v2)
```

Output

```
              Column
0         a  b c   d
1     a      b      

---------v2---------

    Column
0  a b c d
1      a b
```